# Cherrypick to branch without checkout using libgit2

Tags: libgit2

I tried to write a tool to cherry-pick a commit onto a target branch, without switching to that branch. Here's a gist of my prototype:

https://gist.github.com/kastiglione/ac72e5df6b267f936c2c2b9f048069b9

The tool calls `git_cherrypick_commit`, which creates an in memory index. I want to write a tree and commit from that in memory index, using the contents of the target branch – not the working directory contents. In other words, to create the tree using in memory contents, not disk. Is this possible in theory? If the cherrypick has conflicts, the tool would abort rather than write conflicts to files.

EDIT: The above code fails when calling `git_index_write`, with:

```
git_index_write failed: failed to write index: The index is in-memory only
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's doable, but sadly it looks like there's a catch…

First, the index you get back is "what working copy state that commit looks like" (mostly). In "normal-git land", there's only ever one index, the file at `.git/index`. libgit2 doesn't quite require that, so `git_cherrypick_commit` gives you back an index, so you have the choice of what to do with its contents.

So, if you [`git_index_write`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_write) ([and](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_write_tree) [friends](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_write_tree_to)), all objects required to "checkout" that index will be written. It's unclear whether the index you're about to cherrypick is backed or not, so YMMV.

The last step would then be to simply atomic-update the target branch to point to the newly cherrypicked commit, but it now becomes obvious that you don't actually have the cherrypicked commit OID handy, since the index only gives you a tree… I might be missing something though .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with the current error I get when running the example code: "failed to write index: The index is in-memory only". So one part of the problem is that the API currently doesn't allow writing the index anywhere. I would want to write to somewhere other than `.git/index`. But the second thing is it seems I need a way to write a tree, using the alt index, but not using working dir contents, instead using git contents.

Comment: Have you checked what `git_index_write_tree_to` reports ? It should write the needed objects to the repository you want (as dangling objects, actually, since there's no reference pointing to them yet).

Comment: `git_index_write_tree_to` didn't error, but the result was the target branch had been fast-forwarded, instead of a cherry-pick.

Comment: I realize why it looked like a fast forward, I used the same committer signature, rather than creating a new one with the current author and time, as `git cherry-pick` does. It seems like my one basic case is working.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it worked faithfully . And thanks for the documentation PR, that's very welcome !